# Cube vertex/corner blending/fillet algorithm

Tags: cad

I created fillets/blending for a cube corner in 3 cases.

For the first case, the 3 radius are equal. The blending surface is a sphere patch.

For the second case, two radius are smaller than the third. The blending surface is a torus patch.

But for the third case, one radius is smaller than the other two. I cannot figure out the algorithm generating the blending patch. I did a lot of search for papers on surface/edge blending, but didn't find the algorithm for this case. Are there any document or paper on the algorithm for this case?

Could someone give me some hint?

The STEP and picture files for the three cases are attached.

[image: fillet case 1]

[image: fillet case 2]

[image: fillet case 3]

Comment: It's not only liked to the edges of the cube - you applied the larger fillet first it seems. Try applying small first to see how it changes things in your third image? Remember, the algorithm is not applying it to the cube edges and then 'creating a corner patch', it's first applying the large fillets, which themselves will have an edge between them, and then applying the small fillet to those edges.

Comment: The way the algorithm works is this: imagine you had a marble on the inside of the part, and you rolled it along the corner with the marble pushed right up to both faces. Any external volume that the marble didn't pass through is removed.

Comment: I found the (maybe) implementation of this functionality: opencascade/src/GeomFill/GeomFill_ConstrainedFilling.hxx/cxx